# Secure static media access in a Django site

Tags: django, apache, authentication

I'm building a site where registered users can upload files. Those files are then served via Apache. Only users who are logged in should be able to access those files.

I have read [this page](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/apache-auth/) but it seems that people would have to log in twice to access both the site and the media, each time using a different type of login box.

Is there a way around this or is there some other way to limit access to static media served by Apache using the Django authentication database?

I'm using mod_python.

**EDIT**: How I ended up solving this after reading Van Gale's answer and [this](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/b4ceae1956e003e5/):

1. Switched to WSGI.
2. Installed [mod_xsendfile](http://tn123.ath.cx/mod_xsendfile/)
3. Moved all public media files into a subfolder in /media/public
4. Added access to the public folder using an Alias /media/public /var/www.../media/public
5. Added WSGIScriptAlias /media/protected/ /var/www.../apache/django.wsgi (same handler as for the rest of the site)
6. Added XSendFile On and XSendFileAllowAbove On
7. To the Django app I added an urlconf for /media/protected which does basically what's [here](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/msg/f15c3de2417b120e), only modified for my authentication system. It handles urls such as /media/protected/GROUP_ID/file so that only members of the GROUP can download the files.

Comment: The other possible problem with the approach described in the Django docs is that it appears to be using basic authentication - this sends passwords in base64-encoded cleartext, so is not secure unless you also use SSL for all requests.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to pass back a special header to the web server.

You can do it with [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxXSendfile) using x-accel-redirect as in this [Django snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/491/).

For Apache, it should be pretty similar using the [mod_xsendfile](http://tn123.ath.cx/mod_xsendfile/) module ([discussion and examples](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/297cbd7dec84ffb8) on Django users mailing list).

Comment: I'm going to give mod_xsendfile a try.

Comment: It worked! Had to switch to WSGI but that wasn't as hard as I thought it would be.

Comment: In mod_wsgi 3.0, you can pass back a Location with 200 status. The directories need to be mapped via a URL though, which is then referenced in Location. Since URL mapping required, to ensure remote clients can't get to them, you need to use a mod_rewrite rule to make them forbidden if not an Apache sub request. The other option is to make use of wsgi.file_wrapper extension to optimally return file direct from Django. Right now can't do this with Django, but will be allowed in future version.

Comment: An example implementation of the X-Sendfile approach is shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156246/having-django-serve-downloadable-files

Answer (score 2):

If you have freedom to switch from Apache to [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/), then the most straightforward solution would be to use [mod_secdownload](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs:ModSecDownload) which would do exactly what you want, that is, provide application authentication while serving the actual files via web server.

However if you are stuck with Apache, then I suggest [mod_auth_token](http://nixbit.com/cat/internet/nttp-%28www%29/mod-auth-token/), here they mention PHP but you can generate the token in Python or any other language. Using mod_auth_token you will be able to generate the token in your application, and then have web server serve the static file utilizing that token.