# How to allow download of file via Apache with Django's permission?

Tags: django, apache, permissions

Is there a way for Apache to allow or deny a file download after checking with Django for permission?

That is, I want the user to have a permission within Django to determine if the user has the rights to a file. And, if the user has the permission, Apache would start the file download. Or, if the permission is not set for that user, the download is denied.

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Apache, take a look to

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/apache-auth/
- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/AccessControlMechanisms

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible like that. Why don't you serve the file through Django itself? See http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/365/

Answer (score 0):

After more searching, I found this:

[How to return static files passing through a view in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294507/how-to-return-static-files-passing-through-a-view-in-django/2302520#2302520)

I think this is what I will do.

Thanks! :)

Comment: That suggest loading whole thing into memory. Not really resource friendly. Second suggestion they give is redirect, it's fine but not bulletproof.