# Django: Password protect photo url's?

Tags: django, django-models

From my Django application I want to serve up secure photos.  The photos are not for public consumption, I only want logged in users to have the ability to view them.  I don't want to rely on obfuscated file id's (giving a photo a UUID of a long number) and count on that being hidden in my media folder.  How would I store a photo securely on disk in my database and only stream it out to an authenticated session?

Answer (score 6):

Use X-Sendfile headers to tell your front end server what file to actually server.

```
@check_permissions
def image(request):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='image/png')    
    response['X-Sendfile'] = "/real/path/to/image.png"
    return response
```

Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156246/having-django-serve-downloadable-files).  You can also see a [real world implementation](http://bitbucket.org/chris1610/satchmo/src/tip/satchmo/apps/satchmo_store/shop/views/download.py) by looking at how Satchmo serves DownloadableProduct objects.

One final note, nginx and lighttpd use X-Accel-Redirect and X-LIGHTTPD-send-file instead of X-Sendfile.

Comment: That does not seem to work with the built-in server. Is that correct or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No, I guess built-in server would not support such, but then again, it's not supposed to be used in production anyway. Maybe have it as an setting if devel-server is needed.

Comment: Correct, the X-Sendfile header stuff is basically an internal redirect being sent from a heavy weight backend server to a light weight front-end server.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a `HttpResponse` with the mime type of the image and then writes/copies the image file to it.

A simple version could look like the following:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

@your_favourite_permission_decorator
def image(request):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='image/png')

    with open("image.png") as img:
        response.write(img.read())
    return response
```

Also, see this [example for PDF files](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/outputting-pdf/) and this example with [PIL](http://effbot.org/zone/django-pil.htm).

Comment: But obviously requires your Django app to do quite much work.

Answer (score 0):

If it was Apache server with mod_python, this could potentially be an interesting article about [Apache using Django's authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/apache-auth/?from=olddocs).