# How to make a file which is on local server download-able over HTTP in python?

Tags: python, django

Framework: Django
Language: Python
OS: Ubuntu

For example, let us assume that I have a file "xyz.pdf" at "/home/username/project/". I have a webpage with download button. So if people click on that download button, the file xyz.pdf should be downloaded.

What I have done,

1. Created a webpage with download button with href as  "download/" (as you all know this url does not matter much)
2. it is redirected to urls.py and finds the appropriate view say for example "xyzdownload"
3. at xyzdownload I have following code,
   response = urllib2.urlopen('./project/xyz.pdf')
       html = response.read()

The error I am getting is unknown url type: ./project/xyz.pdf

Please let me know if you guys need more clarification.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Where do people click? How do you intend to serve the file?

Comment: If you're using apache, the problem is preventing django from re-routing the URLs that are supposed to serve the static media, you need to set up an alias in httpd.conf for your static media folder before passing off the rest of the requests to Django (wsgi);

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question. I have clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you'd want to just host the file in apache etc., and provide a link to the location. If the file is generated dynamically, or you want to "embargo" it, here's how you might do it with [cherrypy](http://www.cherrypy.org/):

```
@cherrypy.expose
def download(self, filename):
    """
    Download the specified XML file
    """

    # only if it's one of these files
    if filename not in "foo.xml bar.xml".split():
        return "Nice try"

    content = open("/path/to/media/" + filename).read()

    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml'
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Length'] = len(content)
    disp = 'attachment; filename=%s' filename
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = disp
    cherrypy.response.headers['filename'] = 'application/xml'
    cherrypy.response.headers['pragma'] = ""
    cherrypy.response.headers['content-cache'] = ""

    return content
```

The link would be like this:

```
http://example.com/download/foo.xml
```

Comment: I have clarified the question. May be it will help you to understand my question properly.

Answer (score 0):

> The error I am getting is unknown url type: ./project/xyz.pdf

That's simple: ./project/xyz.pdf is **not** a URL. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) says:

> Every URL consists of some of the
>   following: the scheme name (commonly
>   called protocol), followed by a colon,
>   then, depending on scheme, a hostname
>   (alternatively, IP address), a port
>   number, the path of the resource to be
>   fetched or the program to be run,
>   then, for programs such as Common
>   Gateway Interface (CGI) scripts, a
>   query string, and with HTML
>   documents, an anchor (optional) for
>   where the page should start to be
>   displayed.

You didn't provide the **scheme name** and the **hostname**. However, I don't understand why you do this. Calling *urlopen* means: download this file on **my** pc. It **doesn't** mean "give the file to the user".

BTW, the *xyzdownload* view should be defined as @Ryan Ginstrom [suggested you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748205/how-to-make-a-file-which-is-on-local-server-download-able-over-http-in-python/3748327#3748327). Of course, you've to adapt the code to Django.

To read some examples, look at [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/365/). And of course, you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156246/having-django-serve-downloadable-files) question because it's almost the same one you did.

Answer (score 0):

you may try mechanize for text clicking and url followers by regex it

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# Want debugging messages?
#br.set_debug_http(True)
#br.set_debug_redirects(True)
#br.set_debug_responses(True)

# User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

# Download xyz.pdf ;)
f = br.retrieve('http://www.site.com/xyz.pdf')[0]
print f
fh = open(f)

# or you may try with click download just uncomment
# br.click_link(text_regex="download")

# or by url regex
# br.click_link(url_regex="project/xyz.pdf", nr=0)
```

and check huge resource and tutorial here http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/