# IE 8 Crashes when displaying PDF in IFrame served from Django

Tags: python, django, apache, internet-explorer

I have a web application which displays pdf's in an IFrame. I recently made a change to start serving up the PDF using Django instead of allowing Apache to serve the PDF. Initially, I used the [FileWrapper approach](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/365/) to return the file. This worked fine on all browsers except for IE 8 which crashed (maybe other versions of IE, didn't test).

I figured out how to fix this but it was a bit of a pain to figure out so I am posting the answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to use mod_xsendfile as [suggested in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156246/having-django-serve-downloadable-files) with the following tweaks:

```
mimeType,_ = mimetypes.guess_type(filePath)
response = django.http.HttpResponse(mimetype = mimeType)
response['Accept-Ranges'] = 'bytes'
response['X-Sendfile'] = filePath
return response
```

In addition to working correctly with IE / iframes, it allows the file download to be resumable.