# Can I set the filename to which a file is being downloaded to? 

Tags: jquery, django, file, download

I have a bunch of files, that are being uploaded and tagged by users. When another user downloads one of those files, I want to create a filename like this:

```
creator_tag1_tag2_name.ext
```

How can I do that? Does this have to happen on Django side or can it be done via jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your Django view corresponding to your download, you can set the content disposition header:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=somefilename.jpg'
```

A more detailed answer is given here:

- [Having Django serve downloadable files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156246/having-django-serve-downloadable-files)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set returned HTTP header as something like the following:

```
response.headers['Content-disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=creator_tag1_tag2_name.ext'
```