# Serving large files ( with high loads ) in Django

Tags: python, django, permissions, download

I've been using a method for serving downloads but since it was not secure i decided to change that . ( the method was a link to the original file in storage , but the risk was that everyone with the link could have downloaded the file ! )  so i now serve the file via my views , that way only users with permission can download the file , but i'm noticing a high load on server while there is many simultaneous download requests for the files. here's part of my code that handles downloads for users ( Consider the file is an image )

```
    image = Image.open ("the path to file")
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype = 'image/png' )
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment: filename=%s.png' % filename
    image.save(response , "png")
    return response
```

is there any better ways for serving files while keeping the security and lowering server side load ?
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why are you opening the image, only to save it again?

Comment: @burhan I've opened the file so i can access it and serve it as a png image file , can it be done without opening the image ?

Comment: Up until all the cool kids stopped using mod_python you could get apache to authenticate from Django's auth system: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/apache-auth/ but now all the cool kids use WSGI (and nginx). Solutions based on those would be useful to the wider community,

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Your opening of the image loads it in memory and this is what causes the increase in load under heavy use. As posted by Martin the real solution is to serve the file directly.

Here is another approach, which will stream your file in chunks without loading it in memory.

```
import os
import mimetypes

from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse


def download_file(request):
    the_file = "/some/file/name.png"
    filename = os.path.basename(the_file)
    chunk_size = 8192
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(
        FileWrapper(
            open(the_file, "rb"),
            chunk_size,
        ),
        content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(the_file)[0],
    )
    response["Content-Length"] = os.path.getsize(the_file)
    response["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; filename={filename}"
    return response
```

Comment: Thank You , this is like what i was trying to achive , i knew about serving it directly using Apache , wanted to know how to do it better with django views :) thanks for the answer

Comment: Here the file is generating succesfully but with an underscore is appending to the end of the file name ..... like file_name.txt_ , name_view.pdf_ etc., so how to avoid this underscore at the last of the file name ?

Comment: This solution does with Django 1.9 as FileWrapper is not available anymore.

Comment: @azmeuk, With Django 1.9 `from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper` - have a look here https://github.com/django/django/commit/bbe28496d32f76ca161f5c33787d6ad62267fcc6#diff-f6d1c75ec606389da5af6558bf57f171

Comment: Note that instead of the `StreamingHttpResponse` you could also use the `FileResponse`: a streaming response, specifically for files. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects

Comment: settings the response['Content-Length'] will throw an error if the file size is greater than 2Gb. See: https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/issues/62

Answer (score 15):

You can use the 'sendfile' method as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156246/having-django-serve-downloadable-files/1158750#1158750).

Practically you need this (c&p):

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(file_name)
response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(path_to_file)
# It's usually a good idea to set the 'Content-Length' header too.
# You can also set any other required headers: Cache-Control, etc.
return response
```

This requires [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) (which is also supported by [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile) or [lighty](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/X-LIGHTTPD-send-file))

Comment: Heck yeah, works great. Now serving 2 GB files with no django hang, no gunicorn timeouts, and basically no server load. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

It's better to use FileRespose, is a subclass of StreamingHttpResponse optimized for binary files. It uses wsgi.file_wrapper if provided by the wsgi server, otherwise it streams the file out in small chunks.

```
import os
from django.http import FileResponse
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper


def download_file(request):
    _file = '/folder/my_file.zip'
    filename = os.path.basename(_file)
    response = FileResponse(FileWrapper(file(filename, 'rb')), content_type='application/x-zip-compressed')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % _file
    return response
```

Comment: For django 1.10 use,  from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are going to be serving very very small number of such requests, any solution that requires serving your content via django won't be scalable. For anything  to scale in future, you'll probably want to move your content storage and serving to to a separate server and then this won't work.

The recommended way would be to keep static content served through a lighter server (such as nginx). To add security, pass the static server a token from django by setting the cookie or via the get parameters.

The token should have following values: timestamp, filename, userid. It should be signed via some key by the django app.

Next, write a small nginx module which checks the token and that the user has indeed access to the file. It should also check that token isn't old enough by checking the timestamp.

Answer (score 4):

FileWrapper won't work when GZipMiddleware is installed (Django 1.4 and below):
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6027

If using GZipMiddleware, a  practical solution is to write a subclass of FileWrapper like so:

```
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper
class FixedFileWrapper(FileWrapper):
    def __iter__(self):
        self.filelike.seek(0)
        return self

import mimetypes, os
my_file = '/some/path/xy.ext'
response = HttpResponse(FixedFileWrapper(open(my_file, 'rb')), content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(my_file)[0])
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(my_file)
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % os.path.basename(my_file)
return response
```

As of Python 2.5, there's no need to import FileWrapper from Django.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another working solution which loads the file in memory instead in the filesystem.

```
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

from django.http import FileResponse


def download(request):
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    zip_obj = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer, "w")
    
    # put files in the memory-stored zip file
    # add_to_zip is a list of dictionaries, consisting of 2 entries each.
    # [{"filename": "foo.jpg", "path": "absolute/path/to/foo.jpg"}, ...]
    for data in add_to_zip:
        filename = data["filename"]
            with open(data["path"], "rb") as f:
                data = f.read()
                b = bytearray(data)
                zip_obj.writestr(filename, b)

    zip_obj.close()
    buffer.seek(0)
    response = FileResponse(FileWrapper(buffer))
    response["Content-Length"] = len(buffer.getvalue())
    response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=the_zip.zip"
    response["Content-Type"] = "application/x-zip-compressed"
    return response
```