# Python: Serving files, All carriage returns lost in text file

Tags: python, django, file-io, mime-types

I'm using the method described in the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/8601118/2497977

```
import os
import mimetypes
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper


def download_file(request):
   the_file = '/some/file/name.png'
   filename = os.path.basename(the_file)
   response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(open(the_file)),
                       content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(the_file)[0])
   response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(the_file)    
   response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
   return response
```

Initially get data in a form, when submitted, i process the data to generate a "config" and write it out to a file. then when valid, pass the file back to the user as a download. 
It works great except I'm running into the problem that in my situation the file is text, so when the file is downloaded, its coming as a blob of text without CR/LF.

Any suggestions on how to address this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open with binary mode.

```
open(the_file, 'rb')
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

> The default is to use text mode, which may convert '\n' characters to
>   a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading.
>   Thus, when opening a binary file, you should append 'b' to the mode
>   value to open the file in binary mode, which will improve portability.
>   (Appending 'b' is useful even on systems that don’t treat binary and
>   text files differently, where it serves as documentation.)