# Creating spreadsheets for download in django

Tags: python, django, linux, unix

I am using xlrd to create spreadsheets. On a website, a user will be able to create a custom report and download that xls file.

Usually, I am storing files on S3, but in this case, is there a way not to store the file anywhere and just give it directly to the user? Or how should I do this if I don't want to use S3 to save the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[xlrd](http://www.python-excel.org/) is a good choice. About the generation and download processes - it depends on the web framework in usage, here is [an example](http://thadeusb.com/weblog/2010/1/17/download_of_a_filelike_python_object_in_web2py) with web2py.

Comment: Thank you, I did a quick google of something similar in django, do you know of any tools/tutorials there?

Comment: You are welcome, David542. Please, take a look at the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1156246/1367611