# Getting forbidden while downloading file in django view

Tags: python, django

I have this code

```
class DownloadView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pdfform/create_form2.html'


    def serve_pdf(self, request):
        #pdf_data = magically_create_pdf()

        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="http://localhost/static/pdfs/angular.pdf"'
        return response
```

When i go to that page i get the downlaod dialog but i am not able to download the file. it says that

```
http 403 forbidden
```

Now i can directly access the file but putting `http://localhost/static/pdfs/angular.pdf` that in browser

i treid puting  `static/pdfs/angular.pdf` but same error

Comment: I think this page might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156246/having-django-serve-downloadable-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filename in should be just a plain file name, not `http://...`.

So change

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="http://localhost/static/pdfs/angular.pdf"'
```

to

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="angular.pdf"'
```

Also, you need to serve the file content through response so that the file contents are served.

e.g

```
...
def serve_pdf(self, request):
  from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper
  # your code

  wrapper      = FileWrapper(open(your_pdf_file_path))
  response     = HttpResponse(wrapper,'application/pdf')
  response['Content-Length']      = os.path.getsize(your_pdf_file_path)    
  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="angular.pdf"'
  return response
```

Comment: but how will the system find that filename

Comment: @user32, check for updated answer, you need to open the pdf file and update `response` object to send its data.