# Django Serving a Download File

Tags: python, django, file, download

I'm trying to serve a txt file generated with some content and i am having some issues. I'vecreated the temp files and written the content using NamedTemporaryFile and just set delete to false to debug however the downloaded file does not contain anything.

My guess is the response values are not pointed to the correct file, hense nothing is being downloaded, heres my code:

```
    f = NamedTemporaryFile()
    f.write(p.body)

    response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(f), mimetype='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=test-%s.txt' % p.uuid
    response['X-Sendfile'] = f.name
```

Comment: Don't forget to flush the file: f.flush, before anything else.

Comment: For more details on serving files with Django see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1156246/462865

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you considered just sending `p.body` through the `response` like this:

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/plain')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s.txt"' % p.uuid
response.write(p.body)
```

Comment: In Django 1.9 it should be response = HttpResponse(p.body, content_type='text/plain');
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s.txt"' % p.uuid

Comment: This is the correct answer for the question as it is text content that is served. A lot of people who want to serve binary files are also landing here. Answers by @Saurabh Chandra Patel is good for serving binary files

Answer (score 3):

XSend requires the path to the file in 
`response['X-Sendfile']`
So, you can do

```
response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(path_to_file)
```

Here, `path_to_file` is the full path to the file (not just the name of the file)
Checkout this [django-snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2226/)

Comment: I've ammended the code: "response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(f.name)" yet still nothing, do i need to use something other than f.name?

Comment: It needs the full path, not just the `f.name` - unless you are storing the absolute path in `f.name`?

Comment: NamedTemporaryFile creates absolute paths

Answer (score 1):

There can be several problems with your approach:

- file content does not have to be flushed, add `f.flush()` as mentioned in comment above
- `NamedTemporaryFile` is deleted on closing, what might happen just as you exit your function, so the webserver has no chance to pick it up
- temporary file name might be out of paths which web server is configured to send using `X-Sendfile`

Maybe it would be better to use [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse) instead of creating temporary files and `X-Sendfile`...

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib2;   
url ="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=s&chld=H|0"; 
opener = urllib2.urlopen(url);  
mimetype = "application/octet-stream"
response = HttpResponse(opener.read(), mimetype=mimetype)
response["Content-Disposition"]= "attachment; filename=aktel.png"
return response
```