# Download and print Image from ImageField of Django

Tags: django, imagefield, imagedownload

I have an ImageField in models, which stores generated QR codes. I want to add a download button in my html page, which, when clicked, will allow the user to download the ImageField image as a png file. Please help me out with how I can achieve this.

In my models.py

```
bag_qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='qr_codes', blank=True)
```

Currently, in my html file, the QR code is generated and can be viewed. I want to add a button, which the user can click to download the QR Code.

Comment: Could you provide example code in your question? this would help us understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Does this answer your question [Django download image from ImageField](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26577548/7610724)

Comment: @KhalidSaifullah No I actually tried that out but it didn't help.