# how to serve the downloadable image files in django

Tags: python, django, image, media

I have all the images stored at some folder like media in my project, and i have a button in html template that should download the respective image.

Below are my codes

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def download_image(request, product_id):
    import os
    # current_site = get_current_site(request)
    product_image =  Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    product_image_url = product_image.image_code_url()
    print product_image_url, ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download')
    response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(product_image_url)
    response['Content-Length'] = os.stat(product_image_url).st_size

    return response
```

**template.html**

```
<input type=button><a href="{% url 'download_image' product_id%}"></a>/>
```

**result** :

```
/media/productb7ab/product792f2764314f40b8bd3b3d58290765cc/codes/Image_1.png  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
ERROR 2013-10-25 18:46:21,192 (base) (7258, -1248855232): Internal Server Error: /download/code/88/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  .......
  .......
  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/productb7ab/product792f2764314f40b8bd3b3d58290765cc/codes/Image_1.png'
```

But when i hit the url like `localhost:8000/media/productb7ab/product792f2764314f40b8bd3b3d58290765cc/codes/Image_1.png` , i can able to view the image,

so finally how to download an image from the filesystem in django ?

What am i doing wrong in my above code ?

## Edit

After reading the suggested link shared by `Brandon`

I have modified my above method to below code and still the same errors i am facing

from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper

```
@login_required
def downloadimage(request, product_id):
    import os
    # current_site = get_current_site(request)
    image_code =  Product.objects.get(object_id=product_id)
    image_code_url = image_code.image_code_url()
    print image_code_url,">>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
    wrapper = FileWrapper(file(image_code_url))
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='text/plain')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % os.path.basename(image_code_url)
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(image_code_url)
    return response
```

**Error**

```
Error:IOError at /download/code/88/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/productrbab/product792f2764314f40b8bd3b3d58290765cc/codes/Image_1.png'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/download/qrcode/88/
Django Version: 1.5.4
Exception Type: IOError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/productrbab/product792f2764314f40b8bd3b3d58290765cc/codes/Image_1.png'
```

Comment: Do you want to serve the image through a view as an attachment that the browser prompts the end user for to either download or open?

Comment: Actually my intension is to download the image when a user clicks on it..

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156246/having-django-serve-downloadable-files for more info.

Comment: Brandon: I have throguh that link still getting the same error

Comment: The exception seems pretty clear - the file doesn't exist on the path you're trying to access.

Comment: nope it exists i can able to see it when i hit in browser by adding localhost:8000 like `localhost:8000/media/productrbab/product792f2764314f40b8bd3b3d58290765cc/codes/Image_1.png`

Comment: What are your MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL in settings.py?

Comment: Is this in production or development? Are you running with `DEBUG` True or False? What are your STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT settings?

Comment: k i am running this in local development, MEDIA_URL = `'/media/' `, STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set url in the previous view:

```
image_url = Product.objects.get(...).image_code_url()
```

and then just put a normal link in your template:

```
<a href="{{ image_url }}">Download</a>
```

Note: serving files via Django in bigger systems will lead to inefficiency - better serve them via simple HTTP server (Apache or Nginx). More on media management in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/files/).

Comment: may be that is right, but when we given like so if a user clicks on download he will see an image only in the browser right, but what i am looking for the funcionlaity is i need to download immediately when i clicked on the download button

Comment: Because as of now i am showing the image to the user already and below that image html element, i want to give the user an option of downloading the image to this system directly when he clicks on download..... so this is what i am looking for