# Opening PDF file generated by Reportlab in Django using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, reportlab

I'm using Reportlab with Django to generate pdf of data computed on the client side.

Ajax is chosen because the client has non-trivial data to transfer for pdf generation.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:document.URL + '/export',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType:'json',
    contentType:'application/pdf',
    success:function(data){
        // Question 1. What should I insert here to download pdf?
    },
    error:function(e){
        ...
    }
});
```

And here is the view.py

```
def export(request, *args, **kwargs):

    // Perform Ajax check
    ...

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="essay.pdf"'

    p = canvas.Canvas(response, bottomup=0)
    data = json.loads(request.body)

    p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")
    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    return response
```

Question 2. I could not get ajax to succeed with its request, only invoking error callback. The same issue was referred in this question

[ReportLab in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210493/reportlab-in-django)

but it wasn't answered. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution would be to use a standard form instead of ajax.

You can put a form in your html (or build it using JS)

```
<form id="my_form" action="export" method="post">
    <input id="my_form_data" type="hidden" name="data" />
</form>
```

Then, when you want your data sent, using JS:

```
$('#my_form_data').value(JSON.stringify(data));
$('#my_form').submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't download a file via ajax. But you can use this library: [jquery.fileDownload](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload).

> jQuery File Download is a cross server platform compatible jQuery plugin that allows for an Ajax-like file download experience that isn’t normally possible using the web.