# Python- Django: How to force users to download Video instead of playing it ina new tab?

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I am currently developing an application where in users can download youtube video.However when I am trying to give a href link , it is streaming the video in another tab rather than popping up save as option in FireFox/Chrome.How should i force the browsers to show download popup?

**My Views.py**

Dow is a  basic function using pafy.

```
def res(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
      url = request.POST['ylink']
      res = dow(url)
      # response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myfile.m4a'
      return render(request,"result.html",{'res':res})
```

**HTML :**

```
<html>
  <h1><a href = "{{res}}">Click Here to Download the Video</a></h1>
</html>
```

**I read about content disposition in other questions but all of them are related to HttpResponse which I am not using here.
P.S : I am a beginner in Django trying to be a pro! over time**

Comment: Replication? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156246/having-django-serve-downloadable-files

Comment: Hi,I didnt get you.I am trying to render this file.However, it is still streaming despite giving content disposition value in render function.I am sorry I am just a beginner @Eylen