# How to return the file data to browser using Python and Django?

Tags: python, django

I need to return the file data while running the URL to the browser using Python. Here is my code:

```
def createfile(request):
    if request.method == 'GET' and 'q' in request.GET:
        param = request.GET['param']
        if param is not None and param != '':
            execfile(param)
```

When user will run `http://127.0.0.1:8000/createfile/?param=/opt/lampp/htdocs/Nuclear_reactor/d25/nuclear_vulnerable/hello.py` on the browser the content inside the `hello.py` file should return to the browser.

Comment: Is that a path on the server or on the client computer? Allowing arbitrary code execution like that looks like a great big security mistake.

Comment: File path is from project folder and I also need to fetch remote files.

Comment: Your function doesn't have a return value. Do you want to return the content of `param` or the result of executing that script? I would avoid using `execfile` for security reasons.

Comment: I need to return the file contains only.

Comment: Why don't you need django? If you are using apache, you can conveniently serve files directly.

Comment: Can you share your answer based on my example. ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149113/discussion-between-satya-and-haken-lid).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having Django serve downloadable files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156246/having-django-serve-downloadable-files)

Comment: Simplest solution is to return a `FileResponse`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects

Comment: Please let us know when your project is online so we can hack your server. Might be a lot of fun with such a security hole...

Comment: Actually I need to create the  `Vulnerability` inside the code.