# DRF send media file to download in client

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

im tying to send requested video file to client to start download ..

file addrees(that is hashed) is comming to server, and it should return file to download ... Now when i enter url like below in browser , it works ,

```
"
localhost:8000/api/v1/store/download/?q=e8000074ab4d,eJwLyygpKbDS18/JT07MycgvLrGyMDAw0C8tyMlPTNFPy8xJ1U9M1MstMOEqMODSAwB4gQ8P"
```

but in client side when i make the same request i takes error like this:

```
Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
```

in firefox and in chrome i takes empety response frome server

my view is like this

```
class DownloadVideoAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, ):
        query = request.GET.get('q')
        pre = query.split(",")
        hash = pre[0]
        dec = pre[1]
        de_hash = decode_data(hash, dec)
        if de_hash is not None:
            resp = HttpResponse()
            resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % de_hash
            resp['content_type'] = 'application/force-download'
            return resp
        else:
            return Response(status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

where is the problem and how can i fix it?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156246/having-django-serve-downloadable-files

Comment: "but in client side when i make the same request i takes error"  -- can you show the client side code that is making the request?