# What is the best way to download log file (large text file) from server service

Tags: python, django, download, stream, python-requests

In my production have folder to store the log file. I want to make the html page to download 'log file' (large .txt file, around 1.5 gb/file) from server to client computer using Django (python) views. What is the best solution to do that (no lose data in downloaded file, good performance)

now i use this code but the size of downloaded file is less than the original file in the server :C

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
    response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/force-download")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
    return response
```

Comment: Please take a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156246/having-django-serve-downloadable-files, might be useful

Comment: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/365/ - have a look

Comment: maybe you should use FTP or SSH instead web page.

Comment: BTW: some tools can resume downloading after loosing connection and they can use [HTTP/Range_requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) to asks for data from some range - so they don't have to download again all from beginning. OR they can use it to download at the same different ranges in separated thread. But web page may have to check if client ask for some range. It can be usefull when you have big file to download.

Comment: BTW: Using ZIP file you could make this file smaller and uncompressing it you will get warning if file is broken. Without ZIP or some control codes you don't know if data are correct.