# Django - can't download file (showed as text instead)

Tags: python, django, pdf, download, bytesio

I have a pdf in my static files, I need to add it some text and let the user download it, but the download part gives me some problems, here is part of my code:

**views.py**

```
import io
from werkzeug.wsgi import FileWrapper
from pathlib import Path
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from django.http import HttpResponse, FileResponse

def downloadpdf(request):
    pdf_path = (Path.home()/"bot"/"mysite"/"static"/"images"/"tesseragenerica.pdf")

    # 1
    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(str(pdf_path))
    packet = io.BytesIO()

    # create a new PDF with Reportlab
    can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
    testo = "text to add" #in future "text to add" will be the username
    can.drawString(5, 5, testo)
    can.save()

    #move to the beginning of the StringIO buffer
    packet.seek(0)

    new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)

    # read your existing PDF
    existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open("/home/myusername/bot/mysite/static/images/tesseragenerica.pdf", "rb"))

    output = PdfFileWriter()

    # add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page
    page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
    page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
    output.addPage(page)

    # finally, write "output" to a real file
    outputStream = open("destination3.pdf", "wb")
    output.write(outputStream)
    outputStream.close()
    return FileResponse(FileWrapper(packet), as_attachment=True, filename='hello.pdf')
```

The code for adding text to pdf is correct because in local it works so i think the problem is what i'm putting as the first argument of FileResponse, if I put FileWrapper(packet) for example instead of making me download the file i see this on my browser:

```
%PDF-1.3 %���� ReportLab Generated PDF document http://www.reportlab.com 1 0 obj << /F1 2 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /BaseFont /Helvetica /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Name /F1 /Subtype /Type1 /Type /Font >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Contents 7 0 R /MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ] /Parent 6 0 R /Resources << /Font 1 0 R /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ] >> /Rotate 0 /Trans << >> /Type /Page >> endobj 4 0 obj << /PageMode /UseNone /Pages 6 0 R /Type /Catalog >> endobj 5 0 obj << /Author (anonymous) /CreationDate (D:20210718122806+00'00') /Creator (ReportLab PDF Library - www.reportlab.com) /Keywords () /ModDate (D:20210718122806+00'00') /Producer (ReportLab PDF Library - www.reportlab.com) /Subject (unspecified) /Title (untitled) /Trapped /False >> endobj 6 0 obj << /Count 1 /Kids [ 3 0 R ] /Type /Pages >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Filter [ /ASCII85Decode /FlateDecode ] /Length 97 >> stream GapQh0E=F,0U\H3T\pNYT^QKk?tc>IP,;W#U1^23ihPEM_?CW4KISh__N8"+NKVeK&quKrKuB2i9neZ[Kb,ht63StAffBaV~>endstream endobj xref 0 8 0000000000 65535 f 0000000073 00000 n 0000000104 00000 n 0000000211 00000 n 0000000404 00000 n 0000000472 00000 n 0000000768 00000 n 0000000827 00000 n trailer << /ID [<75dce57879667ca53ee6edf7352f4f98><75dce57879667ca53ee6edf7352f4f98>] % ReportLab generated PDF document -- digest (http://www.reportlab.com) /Info 5 0 R /Root 4 0 R /Size 8 >> startxref 1013 %%EOF
```

Which i think it's a pdf file but can't understand why the browser show me it instead of downloading it. I think (and hope) that i'm close to the solution but i don't know what i'm doing wrong. What can I do to make the pdf downloadable? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser shows the file response if it is a recognizable format to the browser. As browsers recognize it, the browsers shows a preview. If you want to force the user to download it, there is two methods.

First, if you are linking to the download url, add a download attribute to the link from html. `<a href="download/example.pdf" download>download me pls</a>`

If you want to do it from python, or **have** to do it in python, then you can return an `HttpResponse` object, but with a content_type that forces a download. Example:

```
def download(request, path):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/force-download")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

Resource: [Having Django serve downloadable files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156246/having-django-serve-downloadable-files)

Comment: Thanks, i've resolved the problem adding the code below, basically it creates a file, save it in a variable, delete the original pdf and let the user download it from the variable 'pdf'
`    pdf = open('destinationutente.pdf', 'rb')
    os.remove('destinationutente.pdf')
    return FileResponse(pdf, as_attachment=True, filename='hello.pdf')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with less code. If your file path static instead of dynamic like below, you can change with `file_path = "/static/your_file_path/"`

```
def download_file_from_server(request):
    file_path = request.GET["file_path"]
    file = open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, file_path), 'rb')
    response = FileResponse(file)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

When you return the FileResponse (or HttpResponse), make sure you are returning it - unaltered - to view caller.  After tearing out my hair for a couple of days, reading this question and several related ones, and hearing everyone say "just use FileResponse with as_attachment=True, and your file will download!", I  was not happy at all to see my file displayed as a web page.

I finally decided to trace my code execution, tracing from:

```
    resp = FileResponse(open(fName+ExcelWorkbook_fileext, 'rb'),
                            as_attachment=True,
                            filename=SQLResultPrefix+ExcelWorkbook_fileext)
    # lines below are needed if you use HttpResponse rather than FileResponse(..., as_attachment=True, ...)
    # resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + SQLResultPrefix+ExcelWorkbook_fileext + '"'
    # resp['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
    return resp
```

the return was not to the original view caller, but to a "traffic-cop" routine responsible for parsing and dispatching user requests.  The called routine would put together it's HTML and usually return a render(req,templt,cntext) to the traffic-cop.  The above code returned its response to the traffic-cop.

The traffic-cop then set retHTTP = *return value*, and then

```
    return HttpResponse(retHTTP)
```

That's not a problem if you're just displaying web pages, but if retHTTP contains HTML header information (like Content-Disposition), HttpResponse gets rid of that and replaces it with its own header, suitable for display pages.

The moral of the story is this:
**When you return the FileResponse (or HttpResponse), make sure you are returning it - unaltered - to view caller**

If it's not clear, the fix that finally let me download files was to change the above line in the traffic-cop to

```
    if isinstance(retHTTP, HttpResponseBase):
        return retHTTP
    else:
        return HttpResponse(retHTTP)
```

(which is really what it should have been in the first place!)